# Center one row in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table of 5 images using bootstrap grid system.
Currently it's showing this way. (Assuming X is the image).

x x

x x

x

I will like that the last x to be in the center.

This is the way I'm displaying the images.
I have a jsbin http://output.jsbin.com/rojipeqazu showing my results.
Copying part of my code, basically I'm repeating this 3 times.

Any idea how to do it?

```
      <div class="divide10"></div>
      <div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="caption-overlay">
          <figure><a href="#"><img src="http://inmufest.com/images/pepsi_147x200.jpg" alt="" /> </a></figure>
          <div class="caption bottom-right">
            <div class="title">
              <a href="#"><h3 class="main-title layer">Pepsi</h3></a>
            </div>
            <!--/.title -->
          </div>
          <!--/.caption -->
      </div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="caption-overlay">
          <figure><a href="#"><img src="http://inmufest.com/images/pepsi_147x200.jpg" alt="" /> </a></figure>
          <div class="caption bottom-right">
            <div class="title">
              <a href="#"><h3 class="main-title layer">Pepsi</h3></a>
            </div>
            <!--/.title -->
          </div>
          <!--/.caption -->
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: The idea of a grid system is that the content is in a grid. Centering the last one defies that so you might wonder whether you actually want a grid, or maybe a dynamic overflow of images. For instance, if you have a bunch of `display: inline-block` elements inside a `text-align: center` container, you will probably get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align: center">` on last row. Boom done. MAGICAL

"What is this" you ask? I doubled the column width and aligned content to center.

**PS:** I recommend adding the `style="text-align: center"` to all `col-sm-#`s so it looks good... just a designer tip

Answer (score 0):

This should center it for you.

```
<span class="col-md-12">
<span class="col-md-6">//image here
</span>
<span class="col-md-6">//image here
</span>
<span class="col-md-6">//image here
</span>
<span class="col-md-6">//image here
</span>
<span class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 
col-md-offset-3">//image here
</span>
</span>
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

if i understood your question this is the better way for me.

```html
<table style="text-align:center;">
<tr>
<td><a href="#"><img src="http://inmufest.com/images/pepsi_147x200.jpg" alt=""/></a><br><a href="#"><h3 class="main-title layer">Pepsi</h3></a></td>
<td><a href="#"><img src="http://inmufest.com/images/pepsi_147x200.jpg" alt=""/></a><br><a href="#"><h3 class="main-title layer">Pepsi</h3></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="#"><img src="http://inmufest.com/images/pepsi_147x200.jpg" alt=""/></a><br><a href="#"><h3 class="main-title layer">Pepsi</h3></a></td>
<td><a href="#"><img src="http://inmufest.com/images/pepsi_147x200.jpg" alt=""/></a><br><a href="#"><h3 class="main-title layer">Pepsi</h3></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><img src="http://inmufest.com/images/pepsi_147x200.jpg" alt=""/></a><br><a href="#"><h3 class="main-title layer">Pepsi</h3></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good solution, but where's that bootstrap at?